# Erro ao printar styles e scripts em blade templates?

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Tenho um CMS que esta usando o Elementor para gerar páginas dinamicamente, isso salva meu html css e script no banco. Tive um problema na questão das tags `<style>` e `<script>` pois o blade não tava aceitando isso nas templates então criei stacks no `app.blade.php` para eles (Não acho que seja a melhor opção, mas por enquanto vai ficar assim). **Porém podem chegar scripts junto com o html quando printo** e as templates não compilam novamente, ou seja, funciona se a página criada for simples. Por que o blade não 'compila' as templates quando uso scripts e styles direto nelas? E tem alguma de resolver essa questão?

```php
@extends('front.layouts.page') 
@section('content')
<div class="cursosPage ui-container-bottom">
  <the-pages-scroll></the-pages-scroll>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {!! $dynamicPage['html'] !!}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@push('styles')
  <style>
    {{ $dynamicPage['css'] }}
  </style>
@endpush 
@push('scripts')
  <script>
      {{ $dynamicPage['javascript'] }}
  </script>
@endpush @endsection
```

**@EDIT:** Erro no console (exibe todo o código chamado no `@extends`)

[image: Erro quando alguma tag <script> ou <style> existe]

Comment: A sintaxe `{!! valor !!}` não escapa nada por isso o html é suposto ser interpretado normalmente. Qual o erro que dá ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, ta ai. Lembrando que só da esse erro se tiver uma tag `<script>` ou `<style>` dentro do html

Comment: @TaylorRoos Você poderia coloca na sua pergunta o que de fato tem dentro da variável $dynamicPage['html'],  $dynamicPage['css'] e  $dynamicPage['javascript' ]? Pode ser um exemplo. Por que eu fiz um teste agora contendo css, html e js nessa ordem dentro de uma variável ou em três separadas e funcionou.. utilize {!! !!} na variável do css e do javascript para renderizar o html em vez de {{ }}, pode ser esse o seu problema.

Answer (score -1):

Esse erro ta pedindo pra você declarar a `<div class="app"></div>`

Answer (score -1):

As variáveis que você está baixando nessa view não estariam sendo carregadas posteriormente na ordem que você espera, dessa forma provavelmente a itens do seu vue que estão carregando em ordem errada.

Edita a pergunta com o erro ao adicionar as tags no app.blade diretamente.

Dá uma olhada nesse link sobre análise da ordem do blade.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496506/how-can-i-straighten-out-laravel-blade-extends-order-of-execution